# Apple XCode CoreData SQLite file location keeps moving

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, swiftui

I am writing my first CoreData application in Swift and SwiftUI. I have the basics working and am pretty happy with it. I am using SQLiteStudio 3.2.1 to be able to look at the DB independent of my code. I can find the *.sqlite file pretty easily using the "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" and "-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1" CoreData run time options in XCode (11.4). Everything works well.

The problem I run into is every now and then the SQLiteStudio stops showing any updates the app makes when debugging, and the debugged app in the simulator only sees new entries, not what was already there in the DB. I was confused for a bit, but then I did a 'find' for the *.sqlite file and found that it is switching now and then to a new file. I thought maybe it made a new file if I stopped and started the simulator, but when I tried that it did not make a new file. I thought maybe if I shut down XCode and started back up it would make a new file, but that did not make a new file either. It seems to make a new file almost at random.

Does anyone know what causes XCode to generate a new *.sqlite file for applications it is running? I would like to turn it off so that it keeps using the same *.sqlite file, which will make testing easier.

Thanks for any and all ideas.

Comment: Not sure what your app is, but if you change simulators and/or uninstall and reinstall your app IN the simulator, that will happen

Comment: Thanks zaitsman. Do you know if there is a way to override that behavior? It would seem that would make testing a bit complicated. I notice that even if I shut down the simulator and restart it, it does not create a new DB, and sometimes it seems to create a new DB even if I just leave XCode and the simulator running for a few days. It does not do it very often, maybe once ever week or two, but I can not pin down any pattern. What constitutes a uninstall in the simulator?

Comment: Think of it as reinstalling the app on the device. If the app is new (e.g. new app id, or you deleted it, or simulator is a new box (think XCode upgrade/OS version change)) then you're essentially in a different install of the app. How would you want to prevent it?

Comment: That all makes sense. It just makes tracking the DB with an external tool like SQLite difficult. Each time the app re-installs on the simulator you have to find the file and connect to it in SQLite. Not a terrible thing, just tedious. Thanks for you help, I think my answer is that I need to be more careful and controlled about when the app re-installs in the simulator! Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Or, you know, you can just write a bash file to watch the simulators folders and everytime the new one is created, open that with your SQLiteStudio...

Comment: Finding the new DB is easy, putting in the Core Data command line arguments I mentioned in the post causes an output line in the log of the app to contain the fully qualified path of the DB in use. It is just annoying to have to start a new DB as all your test data is of course gone (well, still there but in the old DB). It seems like there ought to be a way, just for testing, to fix it to a single DB instance, but for production, let it create a new one every time the app is installed.

Comment: From a testing perspective, having the data removed and then using a process to preload test data is a good thing. That way the state of the database is always known and is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution to my problem. It turns out that Core Data creates a URL to where it will store the DB on the creation of the NSPersistentContainer object and stores it in the array of NSPersistentStoreDescription objects that it keeps. I assume there is code inside Core Data that constructs that URL out of a number of properties, including what simulator is targeted for the run under XCode. Hence if the simuilator changes, or the app is uninstalled and re-installed in the simulator, when XCode goes to start the new one it sees the new location for the simulator, and uses that as the base path for the URL object that Core Data uses to locate the SQLite DB.

So because I want to fix the DB in a fixed location while I am buidling and debugging the application, I simply overwrote the URL object in the NSPersistentStoreDescription object in the array inside the container with the URL object that pointed to where I wanted the DB to land. I wrapped that in an #if DEBUG conditional compile so that I would not accidentally leave that code in a production build.

To do this I added the code to the AppDelegate in the lazy load creation of the Persistent Container (code generated by XCode). The code looks like this (the only new code is the code in the conditional compile);

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestDB")

#if DEBUG
  container.persistentStoreDescriptions[0].url = 
     URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/justme/Documents/code/data/TestDB.sqlite")
#endif
```

I have tested this and it seems to be working fine. If the DB does not exist, it is created at that path, and if it is already there, it is used. I can uninstall the application and then restart, and it still uses the same DB instance.

I hope that helps others, and thanks to 'zaitsman' for giving me some backround that helped me chart a path to make this work.

Comment: This is very very very helpful, TANKS, I've been looking for hours for solutions to load my DB into Core Data Lab because if the URL changing all the time, or the simulator breaking the link

Comment: I am glad this was able to help you. I use this technique all the time and it works great for me.